# Gstreamer debug output over multiple files for a plugin

Tags: c++, gstreamer

I'm trying to figure out how to setup Gstreamer 0.10 logging in a plugin I'm writing. The plugin spans multiple source files and I can't figure out how to get the GST_WARNING,GST_DEBUG,etc. macros to work from outside of the main source file.

Say I have two files:

```
plugin1.cpp
plugin1_helper.cpp
```

The plugin1.cpp is generated from a template and the debug category is defined as follows.

```
GST_DEBUG_CATEGORY_STATIC (gst_plugin1_debug);
#define GST_CAT_DEFAULT gst_plugin1_debug
```

It initialized inside the plugin1_init() function.

```
GST_DEBUG_CATEGORY_INIT (gst_plugin1_debug, "plugin1",
    0, "Template plugin1");
```

I looked at the tutorial http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Basic+tutorial+11%3A+Debugging+tools but wasn't able to figure out how to deal with multiple files.

When I call GST_WARNING from within plugin_helper I get an output with a `default` debug category instead of `plugin1`.

If I try to create a new category for the helper file I get the following output.

```
(gst-launch-0.10:4422): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_debug_log_valist: assertion 'category != NULL' failed
```

So how can GST_DEBUG work with multiple source files for a plugin?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems I was not very through looking through gstinfo.h before posting.

In order to use multiple files, you need to define the variable that keeps track of the gstreamer logging group differently. The tutorial shows how to use a static logging variable which is only visible inside the file it's defined in.

In order to use multiple files define the logging variable without static inside plugin1.cpp:

```
GST_DEBUG_CATEGORY (gst_slxgpu_debug);
#define GST_CAT_DEFAULT gst_slxgpu_debug
```

And then in the file you want to use it, define it as extern inside plugin1_helper.cpp:

```
GST_DEBUG_CATEGORY_EXTERN (gst_slxgpu_debug);
#define GST_CAT_DEFAULT gst_slxgpu_debug
```